# How to set up favicon.ico route in local web2py

Tags: url-routing, web2py

I'm testing my web2py server using the default method (`python web2py.py`) running on 127.0.0.1:8000, and in my routes.py file I have

```
routes_in=(
    (r'.*/favicon.ico',r'/myapp/static/images/favicon.ico'),
)
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/static/images/favicon.ico` I can see the icon, but when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico` I still can't. What am I doing wrong? I've tried matching against r'.*:/favicon.ico' and various other combos too, FWIW.

Edit: The routes.py file also has the line

```
routers = dict(BASE=dict(default_application='myapp',),)
```

earlier in the file, which seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: p.s. I can tell the routes.py file is being read, because I also have `routes_onerror = [('myapp/404', '/myapp/default/custom_404.html')]` set, and the 404 error page which I get is the custom one.

Comment: Have you reloaded routes (via the admin app) or restarted the web server?

Comment: @anthony: yes, I have done both. I guess this *should* work then?

Comment: I have tested on a fresh install and it does work, so I will try and triage and report back

Comment: @Anthony: the problem seems to be a line such as `routers = dict(BASE=dict(default_application='my app',),)` earlier in the routes file. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#URL-rewrite), you cannot mix the parameter-based and pattern-based rewrite systems. The existence of the `routers` dictionary in `routes.py` triggers usage of the parameter-based system, so `routes_in` will be ignored, as it is relevant only with the pattern-based system.

If you would like to use the parameter-based system, within `routers`, specify a `default_application`, and put the `favicon.ico` file in the default application's `/static` folder.

Comment: If I want to specify a default application with the favicon in static/images/favicon.ico, what is the recommended do I do it? Can I e.g. specify `root_static=[]` and use routes_in for favicons?

Comment: No, you cannot mix `routers` and `routes_in`. If you want to use `routers`, you are limited to putting `favicon.ico` in the `/static` folder of the default application. Alternatively, you can simply configure your web server to serve `favicon.ico` directly without any involvement of web2py.